# MPI functions to 'listen' for if a node is ready

Tags: mpi, message-passing

I would like to have one 'parent' node which generates data and passes it to worker nodes who will do the computations necessary on the data.

I would like the parent node to sit around and 'listen' for when a worker node tells him he is ready to receive the data.

What is the best way to accomplish this? What functions should I use for this? if I use MPI_Send(...) then I have to know which node I am sending my data to ahead of time. If I use MPI_Recv(...) to receive a message from rank 'i' saying that he is ready, then won't the parent node be waiting around on a given rank to say he is ready when other nodes may be trying to send a 'ready' message as well?

I am looking for a function where my parent node can listen for any incoming messages or will somehow know when it is safe to send a message to a given worker node.

Comment: You can use an MPI_Recv with a source of MPI_ANY_SOURCE; alternately, you could use MPI_Probe to look for messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the special value `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` for the source parameter in `MPI_Recv`, and then examine the `MPI_Status` object for the rank of the process that you actually received from.

Comment: i thought this answered my question but i realize it might not ... if i have my parent rank looping through "MPI_Recv(..., MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ...)" then it cannot do anything else but sit around and wait. i am hoping to have my parent rank do other things (like write data out to files, etc) while it loops through and tries to send data out. how should i accomplish this? can i thread the parent rank and have only one thread create/send data while the other threads to file I/O?

Comment: You'd simply have to use `MPI_Irecv`, again with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`, and occasionally use `MPI_Test` to see whether a message was received.